# Mirror / autoforward Google mail

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email, automation, google-workspace-for-business

Is it possible to create an autoforward rule and/or a mirror-like service for current users? We use Google Apps for Enterprise (paid version—includes Postini).

I need that emails sent from/to a specific user will also be sent to another email. Of course, this needs to be discrete, without the user knowing that.

Is it possible in any way?

- Having a forward address in the user's settings box is, of course, not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out about Flashpanel -Creating a Monitor User over an inbox.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try [User-level email routing options](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=175745)

Comment: Thanks. I clearly mentioned that these options are NOT what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Google Vault - It's a discrete option, offered by Google - That's what I am using now

- It's not answering the question, but answers the behavior I was looking for. - Getting/seen emails sent to a specific user, without him knowing that.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how Google Vault solves the OP's problem?

Comment: Since I am the OP ^^. My main issue was to get a copy of emails. Google Vault enables that. Correct, it's not answering the answer (also not marked as the answer) - but it gives a similar outcome - IMO